# Same database, different mysql: ENORMOUS DIFFERENCE in query time execution

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL installations, one is on Windows with Xampp, the other one is on Mac. Machines are similar in hardware.
The databases are the same, imported in each MySQL from a DUMP file.

I publish here the two `EXPLAINS EXTENDED`:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED (ON MAC)

+----+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref                                   | rows | filtered | Extra                                                         |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | little_tasks | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | meta_key | 767     | const                                 |  620 |     0.01 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort; Start temporary |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | exp_baby     | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     0.39 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | certs        | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     0.39 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | radius       | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     3.00 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | exp_years    | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     1.00 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | remun_max    | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     1.00 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | edu          | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     1.00 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | start_date   | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     3.04 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | moment       | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     3.04 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | lat          | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     3.53 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | lon          | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |   12 |     3.53 | Using where                                                   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | p            | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type_status_date | PRIMARY  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.little_tasks.post_id |    1 |    24.26 | Using where; End temporary                                    |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL         | NULL       | NULL   | NULL                     | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                                  | NULL |     NULL | Impossible WHERE                                              |
|  2 | SUBQUERY           | spoken_lang  | NULL       | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | meta_key | 767     | const                                 |  620 |     0.02 | Using where                                                   |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
14 rows in set, 2 warnings (4 min 18,58 sec)
```

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED (ON WINDOWS/XAMPP)

+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table        | type           | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref                                 | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | radius       | ref            | post_id,meta_key         | meta_key | 767     | const                               |  619 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | p            | eq_ref         | PRIMARY,type_status_date | PRIMARY  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.radius.post_id     |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | exp_years    | ref            | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.p.ID               |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | start_date   | ref            | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.exp_years.post_id  |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | moment       | ref            | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.start_date.post_id |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | lat          | ref            | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.radius.post_id     |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | lon          | ref            | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | helpeeit_helpee2.lat.post_id        |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  8 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | edu          | index_subquery | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | func                                |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | certs        | index_subquery | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | func                                |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | little_tasks | index_subquery | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | func                                |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | exp_baby     | index_subquery | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | func                                |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | remun_max    | index_subquery | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | func                                |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL         | NULL           | NULL                     | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                                | NULL |     NULL | Impossible WHERE                             |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | spoken_lang  | index_subquery | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | func                                |    5 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
14 rows in set, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

You can see the execution time by yourself **4 minutes on MAC** while only **0.03 seconds on WINDOWS/Xampp**

And here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID,p.post_author, lat.meta_value AS lat, lon.meta_value AS lon, radius.meta_value AS radius, start_date.meta_value AS date_interval, moment.meta_value AS day_moment, exp_years.meta_value AS exp_years
FROM `hlp_posts` p

INNER JOIN hlp_postmeta AS lat ON (p.ID = lat.post_id AND lat.meta_key = "hlp_latitude")
INNER JOIN hlp_postmeta AS lon ON (p.ID = lon.post_id AND lon.meta_key = "hlp_longitude")
INNER JOIN hlp_postmeta AS radius ON (p.ID = radius.post_id AND radius.meta_key = "hlp_resume_range_distance")
INNER JOIN hlp_postmeta AS start_date ON (p.ID = start_date.post_id AND start_date.meta_key = "hlp_resume_date")
INNER JOIN hlp_postmeta AS moment ON (p.ID = moment.post_id AND moment.meta_key = "hlp_resume_availability")
INNER JOIN hlp_postmeta AS exp_years ON (p.ID = exp_years.post_id AND exp_years.meta_key = 'resume_years_of_exp' AND (exp_years.meta_value >= 4))

WHERE
p.post_type = 'babysitter'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'

AND (
p.ID IN (SELECT spoken_lang.post_id FROM hlp_postmeta AS spoken_lang WHERE spoken_lang.meta_key = 'wpjobus_resume_languages' AND (spoken_lang.meta_value LIKE '%Inglese%' AND spoken_lang.meta_value LIKE '%Francese%' AND spoken_lang.meta_value LIKE '%Spagnolo%' AND spoken_lang.meta_value LIKE '%Tedesco%'))
OR
p.ID IN (SELECT native_lang.post_id FROM hlp_postmeta AS native_lang WHERE native_lang.meta_key = 'wpjobus_resume_native_language' AND native_lang.meta_key = 'wpjobus_resume_native_language' AND (native_lang.meta_value = 'Inglese' AND native_lang.meta_value = 'Francese' AND native_lang.meta_value = 'Spagnolo' AND native_lang.meta_value = 'Tedesco'))
)

AND p.ID IN (SELECT remun_max.post_id FROM hlp_postmeta AS remun_max WHERE remun_max.meta_key = 'wpjobus_resume_remuneration' AND remun_max.meta_value <= 5)
AND p.ID IN (SELECT exp_baby.post_id FROM hlp_postmeta AS exp_baby WHERE exp_baby.meta_key = 'wpjobus_resume_skills' AND (exp_baby.meta_value LIKE '%i:0%' AND exp_baby.meta_value LIKE '%i:1%' AND exp_baby.meta_value LIKE '%i:2%' AND exp_baby.meta_value LIKE '%i:3%'))
AND p.ID IN (SELECT little_tasks.post_id FROM hlp_postmeta AS little_tasks WHERE little_tasks.meta_key = 'hlp_resume_little_tasks' AND (little_tasks.meta_value LIKE '%i:0%' AND little_tasks.meta_value LIKE '%i:1%' AND little_tasks.meta_value LIKE '%i:2%' AND little_tasks.meta_value LIKE '%i:3%' AND little_tasks.meta_value LIKE '%i:4%' AND little_tasks.meta_value LIKE '%i:5%' AND little_tasks.meta_value LIKE '%i:6%'))
AND p.ID IN (SELECT certs.post_id FROM hlp_postmeta AS certs WHERE certs.meta_key = 'hlp_resume_prof_edu' AND (certs.meta_value LIKE '%i:0%' AND certs.meta_value LIKE '%i:2%' AND certs.meta_value LIKE '%i:3%' AND certs.meta_value LIKE '%i:7%' AND certs.meta_value LIKE '%i:11%'))
AND p.ID IN (SELECT edu.post_id FROM hlp_postmeta AS edu WHERE edu.meta_key = 'hlp_resume_edu' AND (edu.meta_value >= 3))

ORDER BY `p`.`ID` DESC
```

I really can't explain how this is possible.

Comment: Are the two installations of the same MySQL version?

Comment: 5.5 (Xampp), 5.6 (Mac)

Comment: I have no idea what could be the issue, but a minor version change in MySQL has [more than a couple of changes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/) :), there could really be something that affects your query plan / execution time.

Comment: Couldn't it be some configuration issue? Though I have I never edited them on both installations.

Comment: Yes, it could, but I guess it's better to ask on [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: While this can have a lot of reasons (e.g. if you use InnoDB instead of MyISAM, and thus maybe use different caches/configuration settings), this seems to be a result of execution order (e.g. based on luck). I assume you get no results? The windows version just realized it sooner and stopped after evaluation "spoken_lang", while the mac version got the results for other tables before it checked "spoken_lang" and realized that it cannot give a result either. So you may want to fix that subquery (it CANNOT give a result, check it seperately!) and compare execution time with a valid query.

Comment: Just for comparison: (a) is the Mac version also on XAMPP or something else? (b) do both versions use the same storage engine?

Comment: I asked the same question on [dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185020/same-database-different-mysql-enormous-difference-in-query-time-execution/185039#185039 "dba.se")

Answer (score 0):

I found out by posting the question as a bug [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87756)  that the solution is:

```
SET optimizer_search_depth = 0;
```

before running the real query.
Also updating from 5.6 to 5.7 improves performance.